# Is there a way to detect if my app is cloned in sandbox mode?

Tags: android

Im trying to add additional checks for detecting if the app is cloned.

So far so good, im testing if the package name is the same, if the dot count is the same and some apps like dualspace create a user 999.

But some apps like "Island" sandbox the app and isolate it.

My question is, is there any way to detect if the app is cloned in a sandbox environment?
I searched on the internet but couldnt find much info on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 solutions for that case:

**Solution 1: check permissions**

Most Sandbox Cloned Apps are using work profile so they will need specific permissions for them, I just need to check if they are granted:

*Notice: this will not work if your App also need those permissions*

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Main2Activity.this, Manifest.permission. GET_ACCOUNTS) = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Main2Activity.this, Manifest.permission. MANAGE_ACCOUNTS) = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

**Solution 2: Using [installreferrer](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library)**

I found out that cloned App will throw error code `FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED` when I try access Google Play installreferrer

My code:

```
import com.android.installreferrer.api.InstallReferrerClient
import com.android.installreferrer.api.InstallReferrerStateListener

...

suspend fun getInstallReferrer(): Result<String?> {

    val referrerClient = InstallReferrerClient.newBuilder(context).build()

    
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
      referrerClient.startConnection(object : InstallReferrerStateListener {
        override fun onInstallReferrerSetupFinished(responseCode: Int) {
          when (responseCode) {
            InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.OK -> {
              // Connection established and response received
              try {
                val response = referrerClient.installReferrer
                installReferrer.append(response.installReferrer)
              } catch (e: RemoteException) {
                return@withContext Result.Error(e)
              }

              return@withContext Result.Success(installReferrer.toString()) // ==> Default App will go here
            }

            InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED -> // ==> Cloned App will go here
              return@withContext Result.Error(Exception("FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED")

            InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE ->
              return@withContext Result.Error(Exception("SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE")

            else -> return@withContext Result.Error(Exception("ERR_APPLICATION_INSTALL_REFERRER")
          }
          referrerClient.endConnection()
        }

        override fun onInstallReferrerServiceDisconnected() {
            return@withContext Result.Error(Exception("ERR_APPLICATION_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED")
        }
      })
    }
}
```